# How to undo/fix autoremove's change to initramfs-tools? (Causes error in Whonix)

Tags: whonix

I executed `sudo apt autoremove` to free space in boot. I realized in hindsight that there are better ways to free space.

I don't notice any problems on my host os, but when I start Whonix KVM it shows me an error message about being unable to find the command for initramfs-tools. I have to press any key to continue booting Whonix. I don't notice any problem while using Whonix, but I'm not experienced enough to understand what kind of issues the error message could cause.

What I've tried:

Restarting the computer.

```
sudo apt install initramfs-tools
```

It says it's already installed and up to date.

```
sudo apt install qemu-kvm libvirt-clients libvirt-daemon-system bridge-utils libguestfs-tools genisoimage virtinst libosinfo-bin virt-manager
```

It says they're already installed and up to date.

I'm using the latest Whonix KVM version 16.0.3.1

The exact message I get while booting Whonix (same message in both Gateway and Workstation):

```
Booting 'Whonix GNU/Linux'
error: can't find command initramfs-tools
loading linux 5.10.0-9-amd64...
Loading initial ramdisk...
Press any key to continue
```

Comment: This is one of those cases where the exact wording of the error message would be important. Since you've already discovered `initramfs-tools` is already installed and up to date, there is a chance you're misinterpreting the error message. There is a fairly common error message syntax: `<name of software detecting the error>: <one of the standard error message texts> <the object of the error message>`. Furthermore, the only times anything named literally `initramfs-tools` would be executed should be *when installing or removing a kernel package*, not at boot time.

Comment: @telcoM I updated the question with the exact message.

Comment: Oh, it looks like the error message is coming from GRUB (or the bootloader, anyway)! That is an important detail. Next step: run `grep initramfs-tool /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/grub.d/* /etc/default/grub`. Normally, I'd expect to **not** find the string `initramfs-tools` in any of those files, but in your case, that string seems to have found its way in there somewhere, and I suspect it shouldn't be there. The `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` is auto-generated based on the other files mentioned above, so if only `grub.cfg` has `initramfs-tools` mentioned, it's probably corruption or manual modifications.

Comment: @telcoM I haven't manually manipulated any grub or initramfs-tools file.
I couldn't find grub.cfg or grub.d at those locations, I couldn't find it anywhere else neither with the find commands:
`sudo find / -type f -name grub.cfg`
`sudo find / -type d -name grub.d`
I also tried executing the commands you told me to, and I also look looked manually, but found nothing.

Comment: Although I did find the initramfs-tools file, it's in **/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools**
. Here is the contents: https://pastebin.com/aSXGk3TP

I also found it in **/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools**. The 4th line might be of interest? I wonder if the fix would be to overwrite the previous file with this one. I have so little experience with with this so I would appreciate your advice first, so I don't make a mistake which only causes even more serious problems. here's the contents: https://pastebin.com/Nj4uLTbc

Comment: No, don't change those files. Since the error message appears **before loading the kernel**, it must come from a bootloader of some sort. `/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools` is used when you are installing a new kernel package, and `/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools` when removing one. Neither of them is directly involved in the boot process, certainly not before the kernel is loaded. I'm afraid that a real answer must come from someone who knows how the bootloader is arranged *specifically in Whonix KVM*.